# EPSG for ETRS89 / Lambert Conic in Spain?

Tags: coordinate-system, epsg, lambert-conformal-conic, spain

Official projections in Spain are based on ETRS89 / UTM.

A royal decree says Lambert Conic Conform should be used for small scales. I found a paper that describes well the parameters of that projection:
https://www.ign.es/web/resources/docs/IGNCnig/ProyeccionesMapasANE.pdf

OGC Well-Known Text (WKT):

> quote
> "ETRS 1989 Lambert Conformal Conic ANE Peninsula (ES-IGN-ANE:1)
> PROJCS["ETRS 1989 Lambert ANE
> Peninsula",GEOGCS["GCS_ETRS_1989",DATUM["D_ETRS_1989",SPHEROID["GRS_1980",6378137.0
> ,298.257222101]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECT
> ION["Lambert_Conformal_Conic"],PARAMETER["False_Easting",600000.0],PARAMETER["False
> _Northing",600000.0],PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",-
> 3.0],PARAMETER["Standard_Parallel_1",37.11666666666667],PARAMETER["Standard_Paralle
> l_2",42.83333333333334],PARAMETER["Scale_Factor",1.0],PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin
> ",40.0],UNIT["Meter",1.0]]"
> quote

However, I can find nowhere the corresponding EPSG code. I don't understand why. Is this projection not used in reality? If this is too complicated, I cannot use this because all consultants will not work with it.

I understand I should rather use ETRS89 / UTM 30, 31, 32,... (EPSG 25830, 25831, 25832, ...). But I want a conform projection that can cover the whole of mainland Spain, like RGF93 / L93 (EPSG 2154) for France.

Comment: So what's your question? What do you want to do and what have you tried?

Comment: Pointdump, let me rephrase: is there an EPSG for conic conform projection with ETRS89 datum in Peninsula Spain? If not, why? Given that there is an official decree for it... and then which alternative to use (confirm it's UTM zone).

Answer (score 2):

Note/Disclosure: I'm a member of the Geodesy subcommittee that maintains the EPSG registry. I work for Esri as my day job.

The short answer is that no one has asked for it. The geodesy subcommittee--who are all volunteers and at least partially supported by their employers--have enough to do without searching out CRSs and coordinate operations (transformations)!

It's not in [CRS-EU](https://www.crs-geo.eu/crs-national.htm) either which is one place people go to get definitive information for many European countries. Spain's entries actually look a little out-of-date to me.

You can submit a request to EPSG to add these. There's a somewhat complicated template for submitting the information, but if you could fill out as much as you can, a chairperson will either ask for more information or look themselves. Actually, now that I've looked through the entire PDF, it has just about everything EPSG would need.

If you can find any online data that uses these definitions, that would be ideal because then we could be sure that it's in use. This might be what's needed: It's a [general statement of the CRS](https://www.ign.es/resources/docs/IGNCnig/Metodologia_sistemas_de_referencia_ANE.pdf) (and links to the PDF you referenced which has the details) used in the ANE (National Atlas of Spain) for data between the scales of 1:3000000 and 1:13500000.

Many countries don't publish info on country-wide projected CRS so it's a general issue. (I'm quite excited that the next State Plane system for the U.S. will have state-wide projected CRS. There are only a double-handful (at most) known now.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. I understand that there is a prescription from the authorities to set up a conic conform projection for the Peninsula, but seems it never was really adopted it's strange! So, I won't push for this implementation. I understand that I shall stick to UTM zones for the moment.